# Simplification of a Disjunctive Normal Form Logic Equation

Tags: logic

So I'm fairly new to logic equations and I've been given a pretty big logic equation to simplify and just need a bump in the right direction to figure out where to go. I've been told it's going to be a large answer but I don't know where to begin! The equation is as follows

```
(X ∧ Y ∧ ¬Z) V (X ∧ ¬Y ∧ Z) V (¬X ∧ Y ∧ Z) V ( ¬X ∧ ¬Y ∧ Z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Simplify" in what sense? This is already, as you note, already in Disjunctive Normal Form, which is one desirable sort of simplicity.

But if you mean "compress into a shorter wff with fewer connectives", then start by noting that

> $(X ∧ ¬Y ∧ Z) \lor  (¬X ∧ Y ∧ Z) \lor  (¬X ∧ ¬Y ∧ Z)$

is equivalent to $[(X ∧ ¬Y) \lor (¬X ∧ Y) \lor (¬X ∧ ¬Y)] ∧ Z$, and that's equivalent to $¬(X ∧ Y) ∧ Z$. [Why?]

So the original wff is equivalent to

> $[(X ∧ Y) ∧ ¬Z]  \lor [¬(X ∧ Y) ∧ Z]$

Now, there's a snappy equivalent to something of the form $[A  ∧ ¬B] \lor [¬A ∧ B]$ (using one of the connectives we haven't used so far) -- namely $A \equiv \neg B$.

So the original wff is equivalent to

> $(X ∧ Y) \equiv ¬Z$.

("I've been told it's going to be a large answer". Really??)